# Machine Learning - clusterization (which algorithm to choose?)

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I have a set of a hundred people. For each person there is a table (Time, Point X, Point Y). The number of rows in each person's table is different (about 1500-2000 rows). I want to divide these people into groups, using the data in the tables. Can you tell me what clustering algorithm I can use in this case, or what direction to take in general? I understand how clustering algorithms work when there is one table with objects, but what to do when each object has its own table?

The meaning of each table: a person draws a square, using a special device and as a result we get a table with the coordinates of the point of the square and the time when each point was put.

Using coordinates of each table you can draw this square.

[image: How a square looks]

Comment: The starting point, and the essence of your question, is to define a measure of similarity or distance between two of these tables. When would YOU consider two of these drawn squares similar? (Does the image show a single table entered by one user?) Perhaps similarities between time series (with dynamic time warping) and approaches in 'shape clustering' (a known area of research) are relevant.